How to highlight a Row in the mantine react table?
I want to highlight the whole row of the react mantine table on given condition for example if a value is mismatch in a cell I want to highlight the whole row.
my code looks like
this is I tried
const getRowStyle = (row) => {
    // return hasMismatch(row)
    //   ? { backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1)' }
    //   : {};
    return { backgroundColor: 'red' }
  };
<MantineTable
        columns={columns}
        initialData={skus}
        enableRowSelection={false}
        loading={loading}
        showSelectedToggle={false}
        hideSelectColumn={true}
        showResetAll={false}
        pageSize={10}
        enableColumnFilter={false}
        enableFilters={false}
        columnFilterDisplayMode={false}
        getRowProps={(row) => ({
          style: getRowStyle(row),
        })}
     />

I tried to do it in the < Cell > but no help.
If anyone can help me with some doc or code that will be huge help
